# How to convert form action to Html.BeginForm syntax in Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

How can I convert the following form/syntax to Html.BeginForm syntax in Razor

```
<form action="~/Handler1.ashx" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 0):

Think that you can use this:

```
@Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { @action="your_url_here", @enctype = "multipart/form-data" })
```

, or write your own HTML extension (ex: BeginHandlerForm)